# Stopping a powershell script with a key combo

Tags: powershell

I have been trying to stop a loop in powershell using multiple keys. I wanted something that wouldn't be normally or accidentally pressed, like Fn-F8, or any two key combination. I do not want to use ctrl-c, as the program will run in the background and it will have to do some "cleaning up" upon ending. The code I have below will end by pressing a single key, but that is as much as I could figure out. 
Thanks in advance.

```
$continue = $true
while($continue)
{
    if ([console]::KeyAvailable)
    {
        echo "Toggle with F12";
        $x = [System.Console]::ReadKey() 

        switch ( $x.key)
        {
            F8 { $continue = $false }   
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        # Prints a loop is ended
        Write-Output "1"
    }    
}
```

Comment: If you have PSReadLine, you could try [`Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlinekeyhandler?view=powershell-6) to handle key chords. Not sure if you can easily use it to break out of a script or not.

Answer (score 2):

So PSReadLine does work, but not for my FN key. If I use Ctrl or something else it works fine. But if I use the FN key it gives me the error " Duplicate or invalid modifier token 'fn' for key 'F8'. " Otherwise the code below works fine. I might just end up having to use Ctrl instead.

```
    Write-Output "Press Ctrl+F8 to quit."

    $continue = $true
    while($continue)
    {

        if ([console]::KeyAvailable)
        {

            Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Chord Ctrl+F8 -ScriptBlock { 
                $continue = $false
            }

            Break
        } 
        else
        {

            Write-Output "1"

        }    
    }


    Write-Output "Exiting..."
```